# issues with c99 standard in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, c99

I'm trying to build a C project in Eclipe and I get this error:

" 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode "

needless to say that I added -std=c99 in the project properties. it's the first time I get this problem. any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: How are you building it? Its possible this option doesn't get to the compiler.

Comment: This is why I hate IDEs

Comment: can't use C++. I'm building it exactly how I did before with CRTL+B. this problem was never an issue before. I can't figure out what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your code looks something like this:

```
for(int a = 0 ; a < 42 ; a++)
```

In early versions of C you can't assign local variables inside for loops. Change it to:

```
int a = 0;
//some code
for(a = 0 ; a < 42 ; a++)
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: `you can't assign local variables` you mean you can't initially declare and assign a variable inside for loops.  Also, that's not his "problem" what his problem is, he cannot compile with C99 cause his IDE is failing to recognize it.

Comment: I've opened a new project and copied all my source, header and object files there and it seems like there's no issue with c99 anymore. I wonder if it was just Eclipse going a little crazy

Comment: although now when I think of it, it wasn't just my Eclipse. my partner had the same issue

Comment: @user9000 : Thanks for pointing out my answer was unrelated. After rereading the post I realised I was too focussed on the error and not on the context.